# How to save data into Strings from MongoDB using Java?

Tags: java, mongodb, authentication

I have a document like this in a database in Mongo DB.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5800d904a3e7535f0d2d673a"),
    "username" : "sai",
    "password" : "sai123"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5800d921a3e7535f0d2d673b"),
    "username" : "surya",
    "password" : "surya123"
}
```

Now I have a html which takes in username and password.

How do I save the username and password individually and store them into separate strings from the database in MongoDB?

When I'm trying to query the data using "username SAI" as the key, from DB using a Java code like this:

```
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.DBObject;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.MongoException;
import com.mongodb.WriteConcern;
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.DBCursor;
import com.mongodb.ServerAddress;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MongoDBJDBC {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        try{
            MongoClient client=new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);

            DB db= client.getDB("test");
            System.out.println("Connect to database successfully");

            DBCollection coll= db.getCollection("login");
            System.out.println("Collection POST selected successfully");

            String uname="username";
            String s="sai";


            DBCursor cursor= coll.find(new BasicDBObject(uname, s),new BasicDBObject("_id", 0));
            int i=1;

            while(cursor.hasNext()){

                System.out.println("Inserted doc  :" +i);

                DBObject xyz= cursor.next();
                System.out.println(xyz);

                i++;

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

I get this OUTPUT:

```
Connect to database successfully
Collection POST selected successfully
Inserted doc  :1
{ "username" : "sai" , "password" : "sai123"}
```

How can I manipulate these operations to store username and password into temporary local strings?
Please advise me.

UPDATE:
I've put the entire code. Please help me. I'm new too this.

Comment: Hum storing directly passwords like this in db doesn't seem to be a good approach for security reason they should be slated and hashed

Answer (score 1):

To implement such mechanism you will need to:

1. Create an index composed of your 2 fields with [`coll.ensureIndex(new BasicDBObject("username", 1).append("password", 1))`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.ensureIndex/), it allows to get the best possible performances when it will execute your query.
2. Get the first document that matches with the provided username and password, if a document can be found the username/password are ok otherwise they are incorrect.

*The code could be:*

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("username", uname).append("password", s);
// Gets only the id of a doc that matches with the username and password
DBObject item = coll.findOne(query, new BasicDBObject("_id", Boolean.TRUE));
// If != null ok, ko otherwise
if (item == null) {
    // KO
} else {
    // OK
}
```

*The needed imports:*

```
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.DBObject;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
```

**NB:** Storing directly passwords like this in a db is not a good approach for security reason they should be slated and hashed

Comment: I'm using this code in the main function().
So return is a problem.
Can you please help me a little further

Comment: please check again

Comment: Can you please help me with entire program
The code right from imports please..
I'm really stuck

Comment: I added the imports please check again